# Save depth frame as a PNG 16 file - Kinect SDK

Tags: c#, wpf, sdk, kinect, depth

I'm need to save depth frames as Gray PNG 16 images.
I only know how to save them as 32bgr images.
Here's my code:

```
private byte[] depthFrame32;
using (DepthImageFrame imageFrame = e.OpenDepthImageFrame())
{
   if (imageFrame != null)
   {
        int stride = imageFrame.Width * 4;
        BitmapSource bmp = BitmapSource.Create(imageFrame.Width, imageFrame.Height,
            96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, this.depthFrame32, stride);



         using (var fileStream = new FileStream(full_path, FileMode.Create))
         {
              BitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
              encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));
              encoder.Save(fileStream);
         }
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where your `depthFrame32` array is filled with image data.

Anyway, you said you know how to save a depth frame as BGR32 bitmap. You could then always create a `FormatConvertedBitmap` from the original bitmap and save that:

```
...
var gray16Bitmap = new FormatConvertedBitmap(bmp, PixelFormats.Gray16, null, 0d);

var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(gray16Bitmap));

using (var fileStream = new FileStream(full_path, FileMode.Create))
{
    encoder.Save(fileStream);
}
```

---

Assuming that you already have 16-bit grayscale data (e.g. from the converted outcome of `DepthImageFrame.CopyPixelDataTo`), you may of course also directly create a BitmapSource like this:

```
var stride = imageFrame.Width * 2;
var bmp = BitmapSource.Create(imageFrame.Width, imageFrame.Height,
    96, 96, PixelFormats.Gray16, null, grayScaleData, stride);
```